# Taxonomy posts on Archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, multi-taxonomy-query

---

Hello, I have been stumped for a few days on a perfect way to display the posts using my custom post type (track) and the taxonomies ( genre, sub_genre). When a user goes to http://sitename.com/genre/"sub_genre name" , i want all posts of that sub_genre to be categorized by those sub_genre taxonomies with content.
ex..

http://sitename.com/genre/hip_hop

**Genre: West**

junior test track

**Genre: Old School**

Song 3 track

Rap title track

Song 2 track

This is the code Im using but but its looping all wrong...

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$cam_brands = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'sub_genre' );?>
<?php foreach( $cam_brands as $brand ) : ?>
<h3 class="genre-title"> <?php echo $brand->name; ?> </h3>

<?php $wpq = array( 'post_type' => 'track', 'taxonomy' => 'sub_genre', 'term' => $brand->slug, 'post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => -1, 'caller_get_posts'=> 1 );
$brand_posts = new WP_Query ($wpq);?>
<ul>
<?php foreach( $brand_posts->posts as $post ) : ?>
<li> <?php echo $post->post_title; ?> <a class="sc-player" href="<?php echo get('soundcloud_link'); ?>">track</a> </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Its seems to be going through the foreach as many times as there are actual posts in the genre taxonomy rather than the sub_genre.

ex.

**Genre:West**

junior test track

**Genre:Old School**

Song 3 track

Rap title track

Song 2 track

**Genre:Old School**

Song 3 track

Rap title track

Song 2 track

**Genre:Old School**

Song 3 track

Rap title track

Song 2 track

Any help Please Please Please would be appreciated. My php skills are not the best and the loop is making my brain hurt a little. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you are doing**

Your `foreach` is nested inside  `while (have_posts()) : the_post();`. This while loop, loops through each of your posts (in the genre 'hip_hop').

So for each post in the genre 'hip_hop', you find the post's taxonomy terms for the taxonomy 'sub_genre' (this is the contents of `$cam_brands`). Then, for each associated term (in `$cam_brands`) you get all posts associated to that term (or 
`$brand`).

You final `foreach` loops through each of these posts and displays them.

**What I think you are trying to do**

I'm not aware of any native and straightforward way WordPress can 'split' all the posts of a particular taxonomy term into it's children. But the following will do that (albeit, not in a particularly efficient way).

Also, it appears 'sub_genre' is a separate taxonomy from 'genre' - am I right? If you want a parent-child relationship, you should simply make 'genre' a **hierarchal taxonomy**, and create sub-genres in the same way that you create 'sub-categories'. Once you've done that, the following should work with the below caveats.

```
$term = get_queried_object();

//Get all children of this term;
$children = get_terms( 'genre', 
    array(
        'parent'=>$term->term_id;
    ) ) ;

if($children):
    //We have an array of child (of current genre) terms. Loop through and display the posts
    foreach($children as $child):
        echo '<h2>'.$child->slug.'</h2>';

        // The Query - get all posts for this child-genre.
        $args = array('post_type' => 'track', 'taxonomy' => 'genre', 'term' => $child->slug, 'post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => -1);
        $child_posts = new WP_Query ($args);

        // The Loop - display all posts for this child-genre.
        while ( $child_posts->have_posts() ) : $child_posts->the_post();
            echo '<li>';
                the_title();
            echo '</li>';
        endwhile;

        // Reset Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endforeach;
else:
    //On genre with no children - you may want to do something else.
    echo 'No sub-genre for this genre found';
endif;
```

**Caveats**

- This code isn't tested :D (but should work)
- It relies on your genre/sub-genres all being part of one hierarchal
- Visiting a genre with no children will display the 'no sub-genre' message.
- Tracks which have are associated with a genre term, but not any of its children will not be displayed.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I cant thank you enough!!! This is perfect. I only had to edit a few lines to make it work. `foreach( $children as $children ) : 
` and `        while ( $child_posts->have_posts() ) : $child_posts->the_post();
`

Comment: @Khey glad it worked, I've made the corrections.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I could paginate the genres?

Comment: Independently? Not straightforward. WP uses the variable paged to handle pagination, you would need to register a separate paged variable for each genre, e.g. OldSchoolPaged, WestPaged to store the individual 'pages' you are on

Comment: Interesting. I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you saying I would need to layout the taxonomies in a different variation then having parent and children taxonomies? Is it possible to replace the foreach($children as $child):
with a query that has posts_per_page => 2?

Comment: We can discuss it in [chat] if you like?

Comment: I dont seem to have enough "reputation" to chat.