# CPT archive page - show one post from each taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, loop, custom-post-type-archives, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Basic loop question:

I have a custom post type with a custom taxonomy and 3 terms.

On the archive page (archive-custom_post_type.php), I would like to display one post from each taxonomy term.

Is this possible within the standard `if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();` loop, or do I have to make separate loops for each one?

Comment: You will need three loops with a custom query in each one.

Comment: I found [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41521/15190), which hints at doing it inside a single default loop: basically using foreach inside the default loop. It seems like it must be possible since on a default archive page I'm already looping through the custom post type. The solution in the link is a little more complex than what I'm trying to do, but maybe I can figure out how to apply the same idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went ahead and did the multiple loop thing, as I had done before. I'm always interested in seemingly cleaner/simpler solutions, but sometimes you just have to keep moving. This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php   
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'projects',
        'project_category'  => 'websites',
        'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
        'showposts'         => 1
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($posts as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 

?>

// Get the post stuff here

<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I can repeat this as needed, changing the taxonomy (in this case the taxonomy is project_category) term each time.

Please feel free to comment an tell me if this isn't a good way to do it. I'm far from an expert at the PHP side of WordPress.